# How to promote builds to repository in jenkins multiple branch project

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, artifactory

I need to promote debian packages build in jenkins to the repo (aptly.. maybe artifactory). However, the available plugins seem to be broken for multiple branch projects. Has anybody found a solution to get around this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Artifactory Jenkins plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Artifactory+Plugin#ArtifactoryPlugin-ConfiguringGeneric%28Freestyle%29Builds) for that. Define the deb files you want to upload (metadata will be generated by Artifactory for you). 
Please note that [you need to attach some properties to the uploaded files](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Debian+Repositories#DebianRepositories-DeployingapackageusingMatrixParameters). From Jenkins you don't need to craft the URL, instead add the properties in the "Deployment properties" textfield.

Comment: Artifactory plugin works ok with maven and freestyle projects that have build env set, however the required settings are not available to projects created with the Multi-Branch Project Plugin.